# Calculate $\int_CPdx+Qdy+Rdz$ where $\vec F=(P,Q,R)=(y,z,x)$ and $C$ it's the intersection of $x+y=2$ and $x^2+y²+z^2=2x+2y$

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

Calculate $\int_CPdx+Qdy+Rdz$ where $\vec F=(P,Q,R)=(y,z,x)$ and $C$ it's the intersection of $x+y=2$ and $x^2+y²+z^2=2x+2y$ going on the counter-clockwise direction when saw from the origin.

Answer: $-2\sqrt2\pi$

My attempt:

We isolate $y=2-x$ on the first equation to substitute on the other one and have the ellipsis equation, we get:

$\vec r(t)=\frac12(1+\cos t)\vec i+\frac12(3-\cos t)\vec j+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin t\vec k$

$\vec r'(t)=-\frac12\sin t \vec i+\frac12\sin t\vec j+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos t\vec k$

$\vec F(t)=\frac12(3-\cos t)\vec i+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin t\vec j+\frac12(1+\cos t)\vec k$

$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\frac34\sin t+\frac14\sin t\cos t\right)dt+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\sin^2 tdt+\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\cos t+\frac{cos^2t}{2\sqrt2}\right)dt$

$=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$

What was my mistake here?

Comment: I think you did not find the intersection between the sphere and the plane correctly.

Comment: The intersection is indeed an ellipse in the plane $x+y=2$:$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2x+2y\implies(x+y)^2-2xy+z^2=2(x+y)\\x+y=2\implies4-2x(2-x)+z^2=4\\\implies(x-1)^2+\left(\frac z{\sqrt2}\right)^2=1$$Converting to polar is the right idea. The natural choice is $x=\cos(t)+1$ and $z=\sqrt2\,\sin(t)$, and it follows that $y=2-x=1-\cos(t)$. I think you made three mistakes: (1) putting the wrong coefficient on $z(t)$ (it should be $\sqrt2$, not its reciprocal); (2) incorrectly solving for $y(t)$; and (3) preserving $(P,Q,R)=(\color{red}{y,z,x})$, whereas you seem to have taken $(P,Q,R)=(x,y,z)$